# AFNetworking showing unsupported URL for http get operation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Right now i am using latest AFNetworking library to perform HTTP Get operation but i am getting unsupported URL error message

But when the same, i am hitting in browser i am getting the data

[https://abc.xyz.com/status?id={"request":["123"," 456"]}](http://%7B%22request%22:%5C[%22123%22,%22%20456%22%5C]%7D)

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:BaseURLWithStatusInformation
      parameters:statusId
         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
             NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];
```

so here BaseURLWithStatusInformation is https://abc.xyz.com/status?id=

and statusId is `{"request":["123"," 456"]}` i.e. a dictionary containing array.

Comment: Are you trying to call this url: https://abc.xyz.com/status?id={"request":["123"," 456"]}] ?
Im getting invalid url on my side

Comment: The actual URL is local only for example i am giving this https://abc.xyz.com

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your parameters should be:

```
@{@"id": @"{\"request\":[\"123\",\" 456\"]}"}
```

And your `BaseURLWithStatusInformation` (presumably now called just `BaseURL`):

```
https://abc.xyz.com/status
```

Since you have a mix of query string and JSON there. AFNetworking won't do both. I believe.

Suggested code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
id url = @"https://abc.xyz.com/status";
id params = @{@"id": @"{\"request\":[\"123\",\" 456\"]}"};
[manager GET:url parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Edit: it's probably worth checking what the server actually wants, this mix of JSON and query string format is a little strange. Possibly your parameters should instead be:

```
@{@"id": @{@"request":@[@"123", @"456"]}}
```

Comment: Is there any way i can construct params dynamically , if i have 50 objects ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the GET method is not the best way to pass array parameters to server. At least because the URL has limitations in it's length.

Anyway, your URL should look like `https://abc.xyz.com/status` without any parameters at the end. AFNetworking will add all parameters by itself.

And your parameters should look like:

```
{"id":{"request":["123"," 456"]}}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, so what would be a good solution in this case , if i have to pass a lot of data parameter in URL ?

Comment: @user1227928 The good solution is do not pass a lot of data in URL. Pass it in the body of `POST` request. If the server does not support the `POST` method for this url, ask backend developer to implement it. That would be the best solution.